# Subtract values from vector

Tags: r

I dont know what´s the posible way of creating a new vector from a previous one by subtraction
of the second element to the first one and doing it for all the values of the vector, by
applying Xi-X(i-1)

Answer (score 0):

Use `diff`

```
> x <- c(5,2,3,4)
> diff(x)
[1] -3  1  1
```

Comment: I already posted this option